# Blender has stopped saving my files

Tags: saving

My blender was saving files fine but since a week, it has stopped saving any changes to my blender files.

Im on BigSur macOS. I have updated my blender to 2.92.0, but still there is no solution.
I have tried saving with a different name, saving on a different folder, checking folder rights. All seems to be correct.
Please help!

Comment: What file are you talking about? Blender file or the png render result files or mp4 render result file?

Comment: Hello, are you talking about the auto save feature ?

Comment: Talking about the .blend project file itself. Whatever changes I make do not get saved for some reason now.